# Does Pernicious Poltergeist harm only enemies?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e

[Pernicious Poltergeist](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=965) (say that 10 times fast) says that:

> You create an echo of a powerful poltergeist, temporarily anchoring it to the area to terrorize and **harm any opponents** foolish enough to remain in the area

But both of its AoE options refer to seem to refer to all creatures, i.e.:

> **Frighten:** ...  **Creatures** in the area must attempt a Will save...

> **Telekinetic Storm:** ... ** All creatures in the area** take...

So which is it? Does it harm only enemies? Or all creatures? I'm under the impression that it should be all creatures, but one of my players took the spell under the pretext that it only harmed opponents. I'll allow them to reselect a spell in it's stead if it doesn't turn out that way, but I'm curious: what's the correct way to read this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It harms everyone

As quite often happens, the first sentence is just fluff*.

It was much clearer in DnD-4e, where it was explicit and in *itallics*, but it is easy to see the trend in PF2 too.

---

*) How do we know it is fluff? Because it contradicts the rest of the spell, *and* we see similar things happening with [other spells](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=327), [feats](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=807), etc.

Comment: Do you have any spells or feats where this difference is fairly obvious, or a rule where this is explicitly stated? I also have that general sense from reading various PF2e things, but having some good examples might help people coming from systems with differing philosophies on flavour text, such as 5e. (To be clear, I do think this is the right answer, given that's how I interpreted it, but trying to remain non-bias).

Comment: @ESCE, in the linked Synaptic Pulse the difference is _very_ obvious.

Answer (score 3):

### All Creatures

The rules actually aren't contradictory, as it doesn't say 'harming **only** opponents in the area' or something similar.

Essentially, 'harming opponents in the area' is a subset of 'harming all creatures in the area', so applying both rules results in simply affecting all creatures. Harming all creatures in the area also harms opponents in the area, satisfying both statements.